# How to allow guest users to submit wordpress forms

Tags: wordpress, form-submit, backoffice

I have an issue with form submission for non-registered users on my website.
A WordPress login pop-up appears after submitting a form, preventing its submission.

I'm unable to prevent the WordPress login dialogue box from appearing (which shouldn't be there).

required authorization / wordpress login
[image]

The goal is to allow anyone to contact me through the contact form on my website without requiring registration.

Hosting company OVH

How can I fix this problem?

I have tried different extensions for the form (elementor, contact form 7, ninja form). Modifying authorizations (account, subscribers)

I specify that the site is not a community site, just a bed and breakfast site.

Comment: What, exactly, appears in your browser location bar when it displays the login form? What do you see in the console log of your browser devtools? Any errors? What do you see in devtools' network tab? Any errors? Please [edit] your question to tell us more.

Comment: I have added the appearance of the pop up to better illustrate my request.

I think it's an authorization issue as mentioned, but how do I fix it? 
Shouldn't wordpress allow readers/visitors to fill out a form without logging in by default?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh!  That is a [Basic Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) dialog box. It's generated by your user's browser when your server sends a 401 ("Unauthorized") response to a page. It's actually not WordPress's screen, but rather browser-generated. Ordinary WordPress doesn't use this 401 "Basic Authentication" mechanism.

Why is the 401 there? It's hard to say without looking at the output of your user's browser devtools Network tab as you reproduce the problem. The question is "which bit of server software generates that 401". Once you know which, the question becomes "Why?" and "how do I make it stop?"

It might be something put there by your hosting provider as an "anti-hacker" measure. You have to test your form-posting stuff. And your hosting company security monitor sysem sometimes mistakes you for a cybercriminal when you do that, and blocks your IP address kicking back 401s. Ask your hosting provider's support tech about this.

Ask them to put your home and office IP addresses on their "allow" list if they have one, so you can test your own stuff without getting blocked.